# PHP, manipulation with array

Tags: php, arrays

i have array from POST like this:

```
  '0,id_product' =>  '217' 
  '0,checked' =>  '217'
  '0,price_setup_original' =>  '1.00' 
  '1,price_setup_original' =>  '7.00' 
  '1,price_setup_res' =>  '7.00' 
  '1,price_monthly_original' => '50.00' 
  '2,price_setup_res' => '0.00' 
  '2,price_monthly_original' =>  '40.00' 
  '2,price_monthly_res' =>  '40.00'
```

i want to iterate it like this example, need help!

```
array = (
0 -> array(
      'id_product' =>  '217',
      'checked' =>  '217',
      'price_setup_original' =>  '1.00' 
     ),
1 -> array(
      'id_product' =>  '217',
      'checked' =>  '217',
      'price_setup_original' =>  '1.00' 
     ),
);
```

need help!

Comment: Do you want to change the structure for this array in particular, or do you want a general way ?

Comment: what you have already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$formatted = array();

$post = array(
  '0,id_product' =>  '217', 
  '0,checked' =>  '217',
  '0,price_setup_original' =>  '1.00', 
  '1,price_setup_original' =>  '7.00',
  '1,price_setup_res' =>  '7.00', 
  '1,price_monthly_original' => '50.00', 
  '2,price_setup_res' => '0.00', 
  '2,price_monthly_original' =>  '40.00', 
  '2,price_monthly_res' =>  '40.00'
);

foreach($post as $keys => $val){
    list($key1, $key2) = explode(",", $keys);
    $formatted[$key1][$key2] = $val;
}

var_dump($formatted);
```

[Codepad example.](http://codepad.org/72aWLNbi)

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` will be your choice:

```
$array = [
  '0,id_product' =>  '217' ,
  '0,checked' =>  '217',
  '0,price_setup_original' =>  '1.00' ,
  '1,price_setup_original' =>  '7.00' ,
  '1,price_setup_res' =>  '7.00' ,
  '1,price_monthly_original' => '50.00' ,
  '2,price_setup_res' => '0.00' ,
  '2,price_monthly_original' =>  '40.00' ,
  '2,price_monthly_res' =>  '40.00',
];

$result = [];
foreach($array as $key=>$item)
{
   $key = explode(',', $key);
   $result[$key[0]][$key[1]] = $item;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

done:

```
<?
$arr = array(
  '0,id_product' =>  '217',
  '0,checked' =>  '217',
  '0,price_setup_original' =>  '1.00', 
  '1,price_setup_original' =>  '7.00', 
  '1,price_setup_res' =>  '7.00', 
  '1,price_monthly_original' => '50.00', 
  '2,price_setup_res' => '0.00' ,
  '2,price_monthly_original' =>  '40.00', 
  '2,price_monthly_res' =>  '40.00');

$newArray = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $item){
    $tmp = explode(',',$key);
    $newArray[$tmp[0]][$tmp[1]]=$item;
}

print_r($arr);

print_r($newArray);
?>
```

**[SEE WORKING CODE](http://codepad.org/uJPtDYZI)**

Answer (score 0):

As you want post in object try this,

```
<?

    $arr = array(
      '0,id_product' =>  '217',
      '0,checked' =>  '217',
      '0,price_setup_original' =>  '1.00', 
      '1,price_setup_original' =>  '7.00', 
      '1,price_setup_res' =>  '7.00', 
      '1,price_monthly_original' => '50.00', 
      '2,price_setup_res' => '0.00' ,
      '2,price_monthly_original' =>  '40.00', 
      '2,price_monthly_res' =>  '40.00');

    foreach($arr as $key => $item){
        $tmp = explode(',',$key);
        $newArray[$tmp[0]]->{$tmp[1]}=$item;
    }

?>
```